# What is two way binding?

Tags: javascript, data-binding, backbone.js

I have read lots that Backbone doesn't do two way binding but I don't exactly understand this concept.

Could somebody give me an example of how two way binding works in an MVC codebase and how it does not with Backbone?

Answer (score 285, accepted):

Two-way binding just means that:

1. When properties in the model get updated, so does the UI.
2. When UI elements get updated, the changes get propagated back to the model.

Backbone doesn't have a "baked-in" implementation of #2 (although you can certainly do it using event listeners).  Other frameworks [like Knockout do wire up two-way binding automagically](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html).

[image]

---

In Backbone, you can easily achieve #1 by binding a view's "render" method to its model's "change" event.  To achieve #2, you need to also add a change listener to the input element, and call `model.set` in the handler.

[Here's a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xm5eH/9/) with two-way binding set up in Backbone.

Comment: The answer is so painfully obvious once you see it. Thank you so much for taking the time to provide a clear answer and example.

Comment: And with Firebase comes... 3-way databinding -> View, Model, Database. Just thought that was pretty neat.

Comment: Concise and short. +1

Answer (score 53):

Two-way binding means that any data-related changes affecting the model are *immediately propagated* to the matching view(s), and that any changes made in the view(s) (say, by the user) are *immediately reflected* in the underlying model. When app data changes, so does the UI, and conversely.

This is a very solid concept to build a web application on top of, because it makes the "Model" abstraction a safe, atomic data source to use everywhere within the application. Say, if a model, bound to a view, changes, then its matching piece of UI (the view) will reflect that, *no matter what*. And the matching piece of UI (the view) can safely be used as a mean of collecting user inputs/data, so as to maintain the application data up-to-date.

A good two-way binding implementation should obviously make this connection between a model and some view(s) as simple as possible, from a developper point of view.

It is then quite *untrue* to say that Backbone does not *support* two-way binding: while not a core feature of the framework, it can be performed quite simply using Backbone's Events though. It costs a few explicit lines of code for the simple cases; and can become quite hazardous for more complex bindings. Here is a simple case (untested code, written on the fly just for the sake of illustration):

```coffeescript
Model = Backbone.Model.extend
  defaults:
    data: ''

View = Backbone.View.extend
  template: _.template("Edit the data: <input type='text' value='<%= data %>' />")

  events:
    # Listen for user inputs, and edit the model.
    'change input': @setData

  initialize: (options) ->
    # Listen for model's edition, and trigger UI update
    @listenTo @model, 'change:data', @render

  render: ->
    @$el.html @template(@model.attributes)
    @

  setData: (e) =>
    e.preventDefault()
    @model.set 'data', $(e.currentTarget).value()

model: new Model()
view = new View {el: $('.someEl'), model: model}
```

This is a pretty typical pattern in a raw Backbone application. As one can see, it requires a decent amount of (pretty standard) code.

[AngularJS](https://github.com/theironcook/Backbone.ModelBinder) and some other alternatives ([Ember](http://emberjs.com/), [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/)…) provide two-way binding as a first-citizen feature. They abstract many edge-cases under some DSL, and do their best at integrating two-way binding within their ecosystem. Our example would look something like this with AngularJS (untested code, see above):

```html
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  Edit the data:
  <input name="mymodel.data" ng-model="mymodel.data">
</div>
```

```coffeescript
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller 'MainCtrl', ($scope) ->
    $scope.mymodel = {data: ''}
```

Rather short!

But, be aware that some *fully-fledged* two-way binding extensions **do exist** for Backbone as well (in raw, subjective order of decreasing complexity): [Epoxy](http://epoxyjs.org/), [Stickit](http://nytimes.github.io/backbone.stickit/), [ModelBinder](https://github.com/theironcook/Backbone.ModelBinder)…

One cool thing with Epoxy, for instance, is that it allows you to declare your bindings (model attributes <-> view's DOM element) either within the template (DOM), or within the view implementation (JavaScript). Some people strongly dislike adding "directives" to the DOM/template (such as the ng-* attributes required by AngularJS, or the data-bind attributes of Ember).

Taking Epoxy as an example, one can rework the raw Backbone application into something like this (…):

```coffeescript
Model = Backbone.Model.extend
  defaults:
    data: ''

View = Backbone.Epoxy.View.extend
  template: _.template("Edit the data: <input type='text' />")
  # or, using the inline form: <input type='text' data-bind='value:data' />

  bindings:
    'input': 'value:data'

  render: ->
    @$el.html @template(@model.attributes)
    @

model: new Model()
view = new View {el: $('.someEl'), model: model}
```

All in all, pretty much all "mainstream" JS frameworks support two-way binding. Some of them, such as Backbone, do require some extra work to make it work *smoothly*, but those are the same which do not enforce a specific way to do it, to begin with. So it is really about your state of mind.

Also, you may be interested in [Flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/), a different architecture for web applications promoting one-way binding through a circular pattern. It is based on the concept of fast, holistic re-rendering of UI components upon any data change to ensure cohesiveness and make it easier to reason about the code/dataflow. In the same trend, you might want to check the concept of MVI (Model-View-Intent), for instance [Cycle](https://github.com/staltz/cycle).

Comment: Many developers, especially React/Flux devs don't consider two-way binding a safe pattern for building large-scale apps.

Answer (score 35):

McGarnagle has a great answer, and you'll want to be accepting his, but I thought I'd mention (since you asked) how databinding works.

It's generally implemented by firing events whenever a change is made to the data, which then causes listeners (e.g. the UI) to be updated.

Two-way binding works by doing this twice, with a bit of care taken to ensure that you don't wind up stuck in an event loop (where the update from the event causes another event to be fired).

I was gonna put this in a comment, but it was getting pretty long...

Answer (score 5):

## Explanation by Analogy

#### One Way Data Binding

[image: Model and View]

**One way data binding**: the man moves his hands *and then* the *puppet's* hands move.

In other words, a change in "state" will force a change in the "view" - i.e. changes in the man propagate to the puppet.

The person moves the puppet - and not the other way around.

This is one way data binding.

You might have heard "reactivity" thrown around in popular frameworks like Alpine JS, Elm, React etc: it means when you change "state", the "view" changes automatically.

#### Two Way Data Binding

Changes in the *view* propagate back to the model.

**Example**:
Someone in the crowd shakes the skeleton's hand, which forces the *puppeteer's* hands to move in response - THAT's two way data binding. And that's voo-doo magic. (Personally, I don't like it. You save like two seconds of typing, but there are legit use cases for it.)

#### Front End Frameworks - Application of Data Binding

With certain frameworks like Elm, React etc.: the "model" doesn't change automatically: you need to attach an event handlers to induce a change in "state".

Other frameworks offer two way data-binding - event handling to update the "model" is taken care of for you, almost automatically. Basically, it saves you from writing an event handler (although you still have to *kinda* do this anyway).

Summary:

one way: changes in state reflect in the view.

Two way: in addition to one way binding,  changes in the view can also change "state".

Hopefully you're not even not confused: if you are post a comment.

Answer (score 3):

Actually [`emberjs`](http://emberjs.com/) supports two-way binding, which is one of the most powerful feature for a javascript MVC framework. You can check it out where it mentioning [`binding`](http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/bindings/) in its user guide.

for emberjs, to create two way binding is by creating a new property with the string Binding at the end, then specifying a path from the global scope:

```
App.wife = Ember.Object.create({
  householdIncome: 80000
});

App.husband = Ember.Object.create({
  householdIncomeBinding: 'App.wife.householdIncome'
});

App.husband.get('householdIncome'); // 80000

// Someone gets raise.
App.husband.set('householdIncome', 90000);
App.wife.get('householdIncome'); // 90000
```

Note that bindings don't update immediately. Ember waits until all of your application code has finished running before synchronizing changes, so you can change a bound property as many times as you'd like without worrying about the overhead of syncing bindings when values are transient.

Hope it helps in extend of original answer selected.

Answer (score 3):

**Two-way data binding**

When data in the model(business logic) changes, the view(html) reflects the change, and when data in the view changes, the model is updated as well.

Note: This happens immediately and automatically, which makes sure that the model and the view is updated at all times.

[image]

**Why we need Two-way data binding?**

Two Way Data Binding is used to develop real-time, interactive application. This type of application is known as SPA(Single Page Application), developed in modern frameworks like Angular.js, React.js and Vue.js

Comment: Excellent answer, with clear graphic, but I'm wondering what the benefit is? If the model needs changing, then change the model - and do that in one place.

Comment: @GrahamLaight In short, using two-way data binding we can build real time application. Means you no need to push and pull data from one place to other place in application.

Answer (score 1):

Worth mentioning that there are many different solutions which offer two way binding and play really nicely.

I have had a pleasant experience with this model binder - https://github.com/theironcook/Backbone.ModelBinder. which gives sensible defaults yet a lot of custom jquery selector mapping of model attributes to input elements.

There is a more extended list of backbone extensions/plugins on [github](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/wiki/Extensions,-Plugins,-Resources)

Answer (score 0):

LemonadeJS is another micro library worth mentioning. It has 7Kbytes and performs two-way binding very nicely. You can run that without dependencies or transpiling.

```
<html>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lemonadejs/dist/lemonade.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'></div>
<script>
let Input = function() {
    let self = {
        input: 'paul@beatles.com'
    }
 
    // Any change in the self.input will update the input and vice-versa.
    let template = `<>
        <h1>{{self.input}}</h1>
        <input type='text' @bind='self.input' />
        <input type='button' value='Update' onclick="self.input = 'New value'" />
        </>`
 
    return lemonade.element(template, self);
}

lemonade.render(Input, document.getElementById('root'));
</script>
</html>
```

Source: https://lemonadejs.net/v2