# what is two way data binding in angular

Tags: angularjs, binding, two-way

I am a newbie trying to understand angular two way data binding. In the docs https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/databinding, it mentions "Any changes to the view are immediately reflected in the model, and any changes in the model are propagated to the view". So if there is an input box ( model ) and an expression ( view )  I can see that "and any changes in the model are propagated to the view" works, but I want to see an example of the opposite scenario, ie.,"Any changes to the view are immediately reflected in the model", and how could I demonstrate it my self. Any help would be highly appriciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

## Two-way binding just means that:

1. When properties in the model get updated, so does the UI.
2. When UI elements get updated, the changes get propagated back to the model.

[Also more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13504906/what-is-two-way-binding)

Answer (score 1):

Refer this working code [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/JanakiSathya/37vspyjo/)

**$watch will watch the variable (ng-model) for any changes** in this case and invokes the function. Even without adding $watch, whatever you type in the input box gets updated in the backend automatically. $watch is one way to check if the model is updated properly.

On clicking Login button the latest model value will be present in the controller.

```
$scope.$watch('user.firstName',function(){
        alert("Your name is changed to : "+$scope.user.firstName);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In this basic example of angularjs we are using a directive ng-model. It has two-way data binding ($scope --> view and view --> $scope).$scope is an object which maintains an array $$watchers for each object bound to it and each object in this array has a key 'last' which stores the last updated value in the model.

```
<div ng-app>
  <div>
    <label>Name:</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="yourName" placeholder="Enter a name here">
    <hr>
    <h1>Hello {{yourName}}!</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

In this case "yourName" model is bound with $scope. 
So,angularjs internally looks up for change in this model using $watch and the digest cycle updated all the changes immediately to the view

```
 $watch(watchExpression, listener, [objectEquality]);//Registers a listener callback to be executed whenever the watchExpression changes.
 $digest();//Processes all of the watchers of the current scope and its children.
```

You can also look up for the change in the model in your angular controller as

```
$scope.$watch('yourName',function(){
    //do your stuff when the model changes
});
```

You'll see that if you change the view ie your inputbox,the model defined in ng-model is changed and this changed model reflects back to the view.

Comment: I can be wrong, But what I think/thought is , {{yourName}} is view and the input box itself is model source. But you say - input box as view - " if you change the view ie your inputbox,the model defined in ng-model is changed thus the two binding takes place ". So even if input box is view what is the model in ng-model ? Sorry I am still confused.

Comment: It is a MVC architecture(Model View Controller).So,Model and View are two different things.In the above scenario,input box is the view,and It is bound to a model.Model is an object which stores data.

Comment: Understood.  So the input field is view and nd-model's variable is the model which is monitored by scope. Thanks

Comment: Hope it solves your problem.Please vote up and accept my answer

Answer (score 0):

Two way data binding in angular:

It helps the user to pass the data from the component to view and from view to the component. so this will establish "bi-directional communication".

This can be achieved via [(ngModel)] and also known as 'banana-box syntax', refer it below for snippet to use:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core'; 
 @Component({ 
   selector: 'app-example', 
   template: ` 
               Enter the value  : <input [(ngModel)] ='val'> 
               <br> 
                Entered value is:  {{val}} 
             ` 
}) 
export class AppComponent { 
   val: string = ''; 
}
```

Import FormsModule into app.module.ts to avoid Template parse error while using ngModel:

```
    import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms"; 
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser'; 
    import { AppComponent } from './app.component'; 
     @NgModule({ 
       imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule], 
       declarations: [ AppComponent], 
       bootstrap: [AppComponent] 
    }) 

export class AppModule { }
```

I Hope it's clear.