# jquery .prop() not working for dropdown with checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, flask

I am doing a small project with Mysql as backend, Flask as framework. When I load the page, drop down list should be populated with values from database (onLoading() in my code.When I select "All" option from drop down list with checkboxes(I can select multiple), all the options in the list should be checked. when I am unchecking "All", all options should be unchecked. I tried this code. But somehow it is not working. console.log is printing "Outside" and "Inside" correctly when I am selecting 'All' but other options are not getting checked. May I know where the flaw is in my code.

**HTML**

```
<body onload=onLoading()>
    <select id="nodes-select" multiple="multiple">

    </select>
</body>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $('#nodes-select').change(function(){
            console.log("Outside");
            if($("#nodes-select option[value='-1']").is(':selected'))
            {
                console.log("Inside");
                $('#nodes-select option').prop('selected', true);
                $("#nodes-select option[value='-1']").prop('selected', false);
            }

        });


        function onLoading()
        {
            alert("Loaded");

            $.get("/nodes",function(data,status)
            {
                var tmp = data.output; 
                console.log(tmp);
                $('#nodes-select').append($('<option>', {
                    value: -1,
                    text : "All"
                    }));                          

                for(var i =0;i<tmp.length;i++)
                {
                    console.log(tmp[i]);
                    $('#nodes-select').append($('<option>', {
                    value: tmp[i],
                    text : tmp[i]
                    }));
                }
                $('#nodes-select').multiselect('rebuild');


            });        


        }

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you are using the `multi-select` plugin.

The actual `select` is being replaced by the pretty one. (*and they do not share a two-way binding of properties*).

So you need to call the `refresh` method after making changes to the `select` element.

```js
$('#nodes-select').change(function() {
  console.log("Outside");
  if ($("#nodes-select option[value='-1']").is(':selected')) {
    console.log("Inside");
    $('#nodes-select option').prop('selected', true);
    $("#nodes-select option[value='-1']").prop('selected', false);
  }
  // add the following line to refresh the multiselect element.
  $('#nodes-select').multiselect('refresh');
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot dude...  :D

Comment: @gaby what is `two way binding of properties` ??

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik Please check this post. It answered my doubt. Hope it helps you too :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13504906/what-is-two-way-binding