# How is data binding implemented in SAPUI5?

Tags: javascript, data-binding, sapui5

In this awesome question: [How to Implement DOM Data Binding in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16483560/how-to-implement-dom-data-binding-in-javascript) 
Many data binding implementation details is well explained.

There are also many exploring blogs about dirty checking in Angular, Object.defineProperty used in Vue.js and virtual DOM and so on...

But in [UI5 docs](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/e5310932a71f42daa41f3a6143efca9c), there is only how to use data binding. No details about how data binding is implemented.

I've read docs about [sap.ui.base.ManagedObject](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject/constructor) and [source code of it](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/c728dbc7a5393975e0f2e71a5d4627fb4f7bef13/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/base/ManagedObject.js#L462)
.In the [constructor of sap.ui.base.ManagedObject](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/c728dbc7a5393975e0f2e71a5d4627fb4f7bef13/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/base/ManagedObject.js#L461), it says these objects are related to data binding, but I don't know how. Sometimes I will log them out to debug my data binding, but still got no big picture:

```
        // data binding
        this.oModels = {};
        this.aPropagationListeners = [];
        this.oBindingContexts = {};
        this.mElementBindingContexts = {};
        this.mBindingInfos = {};
        this.mObjectBindingInfos = {};
```

And also lost in [ManagedObject.prototype.bindObject](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/c728dbc7a5393975e0f2e71a5d4627fb4f7bef13/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/base/ManagedObject.js#L2711).

I really hope to learn how Dom updated when data model changes and vice versa.

Comment: A little piece of information : [Handlebars.js](https://handlebarsjs.com/) framework is incorporated in SAP UI5 for data binding.

Comment: If it's just for debugging, maybe the UI5 chrome extension can help. It will show the elements on your page as UI5 elements instead of HTML elements, and it will show the bindings on those elements. Find it here: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ui5-inspector/bebecogbafbighhaildooiibipcnbngo?hl=en

Comment: @Jorg, yes, I know that and [UI5 diagnostics](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/1ff250c2038849f5991209f7e6c36f1f), But what I want to know is implementations details.

Comment: Thanks @santhosh, I found that in [sap.ui.thirdparty](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/tree/88d440e6a9f668cb4d6def7ee237679d1995c149/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/thirdparty), I will dig into it.

Comment: Search for Handlebars.compile, probably.

Comment: It's funny but the angular discussion on dirty checking is practically poisonous. It's so wound up in framework wars that should question anything you read on the subject

Comment: @Jorg, seems not relevant: https://github.com/SAP/openui5/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=Handlebars.compile&type=

Comment: @Tiny handlebars.compile is the function that UI5 uses to crunch the template against the actuals on the model. If that's not what you're after I'm not sure what is

Comment: @Jorg, sorry, I thought you meant search it in UI5. Understand now, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some comments said UI5 use Handlebars for data binding, and after search, Handlebars only support for [one-time data binding](http://ahadb.com/2017/09/21/binding/). What I am more curious is how **two-way data binding** implemented in UI5(Sorry for not making this clear in the first place).

In Handlebars，once you compiled your template, the view/DOM has nothing to do with the data model.

But two-way data binding connects data to a property or attribute of an element in its local DOM. Which means:

> When properties in the model get updated, so does the UI. When UI elements get updated, the changes get propagated back to the model.
>   https://stackoverflow.com/a/13504965/5238583

In the question of [How to Implement DOM Data Binding in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16483560/how-to-implement-dom-data-binding-in-javascript)
, many techniques are mentioned. UI5 uses these two(what I've found so far): [add change event listener](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16484266/5238583) and [mutators(setter)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16485030/5238583)

I used this official sample for example: [Data Binding - Step 13 - Element Binding](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.ui.core.tutorial.databinding.13/preview)

data binding changes when
`oProductDetailPanel.bindElement({ path: sPath, model: "products" });` is called.

Set break points in [oBinding.setContext() in ManagedObject.prototype.updateBindingContext](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/c728dbc7a5393975e0f2e71a5d4627fb4f7bef13/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/base/ManagedObject.js#L3972) and [ManagedObject.prototype.updateProperty](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/c728dbc7a5393975e0f2e71a5d4627fb4f7bef13/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/base/ManagedObject.js#L3197). And you can see it in call stack.

> TL;DR: Core steps are 3, 6, 8

The main steps are:

1. `Element.prototype.bindElement` equals to [ManagedObject.prototype.bindObject](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/c728dbc7a5393975e0f2e71a5d4627fb4f7bef13/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/base/ManagedObject.js#L2711)
2. [oBinding.initialize()](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/c728dbc7a5393975e0f2e71a5d4627fb4f7bef13/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/base/ManagedObject.js#L2784) which means [ClientContextBinding.prototype.initialize](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/c728dbc7a5393975e0f2e71a5d4627fb4f7bef13/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/model/ClientContextBinding.js#L63) is called in `ManagedObject.prototype._bindObject`
3. [Binding.prototype._fireChange](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/c728dbc7a5393975e0f2e71a5d4627fb4f7bef13/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/model/Binding.js#L269) is called in the `createBindingContext` callback. Which fire `change` event: `this.fireEvent("change", mArguments)`;
4. And! The change event handler is defined in `ManagedObject.prototype._bindObject` :

   ```
   var fChangeHandler = function(oEvent) {
        that.setElementBindingContext(oBinding.getBoundContext(), sModelName);
   };
   oBinding.attachChange(fChangeHandler);
   oBindingInfo.modelChangeHandler = fChangeHandler;
   ```
5. `setElementBindingContext()` calls `ManagedObject.prototype.updateBindingContext` eventually
6. In `updateBindingContext`, the call stack is `oBinding.setContext(oContext)` -> `JSONPropertyBinding.prototype.checkUpdate`(because the sample use JSON Model here) -> `this._fireChange({reason: ChangeReason.Change})`
7. For the second change event, the handler is in [ManagedObject.prototype._bindProperty](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/c728dbc7a5393975e0f2e71a5d4627fb4f7bef13/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/base/ManagedObject.js#L3036) (There are many `fModelChangeHandler` in bind functions of ManagedObject, For our `bindElement` sample, we only need this one)
8. In the `fModelChangeHandler`, `ManagedObject.prototype.updateProperty` is called. That where our setter(mutator) is used:

> whenever a property binding is changed.This method gets the external format from the property binding and applies it to the setter.

`this[oPropertyInfo._sMutator](oValue);`. For our sample `oPropertyInfo._sMutator` is `setValue`. execute this, the value in Input `<Input value="{products>ProductID}"/>` will be changed.

Original record here: https://github.com/TinaC/Blog/blob/master/SAPUI5/Data_Binding.md