# React: 2 way binding props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I do a 2 way binding of a variable from the parent component (Form.js), such that changes occurred in the child component (InputText.js) will be updated in the parent component?

Expected result: typing values in the `input` in `InputText.js` will update the state of `Form.js`

In Form.js

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <InputText
          title="Email"
          data={this.state.formInputs.email}
        />

        <div>
          Value: {this.state.formInputs.email} // <-- this no change
        </div>

      </div>
    )
  }
```

In InputText.js

```
export default class InputText extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = props;
    this.handleKeyChange = this.keyUpHandler.bind(this);
  }

  keyUpHandler(e) {
    this.setState({
      data: e.target.value
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <label className="label">{this.state.title}</label>
        <input type="text" value={this.state.data} onChange={this.handleKeyChange} /> // <-- type something here
        value: ({this.state.data}) // <-- this changed
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: InputText component has it's own local state, and the Form component has another state, when you are inputing something you need to trigger an event which updates the state from the form. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38394015/how-to-pass-data-from-child-component-to-its-parent-in-reactjs

Comment: Read [lift state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).

Comment: By the way, this is not what you'd call "2 way data binding" and here's a good explanation - https://stackoverflow.com/a/13504965/5862900

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manage state in the parent component itself instead of managing that on child like this ([lifting state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)):

In Form.js

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.handleKeyChange = this.keyUpHandler.bind(this);
}


keyUpHandler(e) {
  const { formInputs } = this.state;
  formInputs.email = e.target.value
  this.setState({
    formInputs: formInputs
  });
}

render() {
    // destructuring
    const { email } = this.state.formInputs;
    return (
      <div>
        <InputText
          title="Email"
          data={email}
          changed={this.handleKeyChange}
        />

        <div>
          Value: {email}
        </div>

      </div>
    )
  }
```

In InputText.js

```
export default class InputText extends React.Component {
  render() {
    // destructuring
    const { title, data, changed } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <label className="label">{title}</label>
        <input type="text" value={data} onChange={changed} />
        value: ({data})
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

You can also make your InputText.js a functional component instead of class based component as it is stateless now.

**Update: (How to reuse the handler method)**

You can add another argument to the function which would return the attribute name like this:

```
keyUpHandler(e, attribute) {
  const { formInputs } = this.state;
  formInputs[attribute] = e.target.value
  this.setState({
    formInputs: formInputs
  });
}
```

And from your from you can send it like this:

```
<input type="text" value={data} onChange={ (event) => changed(event, 'email') } />
```

This assumes that you have different inputs for each form input or else you can pass that attribute name also from parent in `props` to the child and use it accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Deep. Is there anyway to make `this.handleKeyChange = this.keyUpHandler.bind(this);` and `keyUpHandler` function reusable for other form inputs as well?

Comment: @Jingles I have updated the answer to make the function reusable.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to lift state up to the parent

parent class would look something like

```js
onChangeHandler(e) {
   this.setState({
      inputValue: e.target.value // you receive the value from the child to the parent here
   })
}
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <InputText
          title="Email"
          onChange={this.onChangeHandler}
          value={this.state.inputValue}
        />

        <div>
          Value: {this.state.inputValue}
        </div>

      </div>
    )
  }
```

children class would look something like

```js
export default class InputText extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = props;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <label className="label">{this.state.title}</label>
        <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.props.onChange} />
        value: ({this.state.value})
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass a callback from Form.js to InputText and then call that callback in InputText on handleKeyChange