# Angular Terminology/Data binding

Tags: angular, data-binding, angular-directive, angular-pipe

I'm a little bit confused regarding the different terms in Angular and their relationships.

Do I understand the following terminology and their relationship to each other right?

**Data binding** is the main term which means passing data from the class to the HTML template of the same, child or parent component or from the HTML component back to the class.

Interpolation, Directives, Pipes, property, class, event, style binding and are **forms of data-binding.**

**Directives** are the conditional altercation of the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

Data binding is how you pass data from one component to another component. For that, you can use components directives and pipes.

A component renders its own template.
Directives are decorators of elements and components when you need to change the DOM, but it doesn't depend on a render of a particular template (for example, to add an CSS class or an attribute to an existing element).

Answer (score 1):

**Data binding** is the core of the way to pass data between a template and a component.
Angular is based on the two ways data binding:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13504906/what-is-two-way-binding#:~:text=Two%2Dway%20binding%20means%20that,does%20the%20UI%2C%20and%20conversely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13504906/what-is-two-way-binding#:%7E:text=Two%2Dway%20binding%20means%20that,does%20the%20UI%2C%20and%20conversely).

**Interpolation** refers to embedding expressions into marked up text (template expression).

**Pipe** will modify text in a template expression (interpolation):

https://angular.io/guide/pipes

**Directive** is used to modify the behavior of DOM elements. Be careful with different kind of directives.

https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives

Comment: That is a strange end to the URL: `#:~:text=Two%2Dway%20binding%20means%20that,does%20the%20UI%2C%20and%20conversely.` (containing *"Two"*, *"way"*, *"binding"*, *"means"*, *"that"*, *"does"*, *"the"*, *"UI"*, *"and"*, and *"conversely*). Was that the intent?